# Paypal payment page credicard option not showing in webview android

Tags: php, android, paypal

I have designed one page in php and added option to pay with creditcard and its working fine in iphone,but not showing creditcard option in android webview

I have added **SOLUTIONTYPE=Sole** and **LANDINGPAGE=Billing**

so how to fix that?

some where i have read like : "In order for SOLUTIONTYPE=Sole to work, you must have 'PayPal Account Optional' set to 'On' with the 'Website Preferences' section of your PayPal account.
Profile > My selling tools (or: My selling preferences) > Website Preferences > Update > PayPal Account Optional: On." but am using **sandbox** so how to set that?

Answer (score 0):

Go to Developer.PayPal.com > log in > Applications > Sandbox Accounts > Enter Sandbox Site > log into your sandbox account. Then follow the steps you provided to turn on account optional on.